# Check if Facebook, LinkedIn, Gmail apps are installed

Tags: ios, facebook, gmail, installation, linkedin-api

IS there a way we can check if Facebook, LinkedIn, gmail app are installed programatically. As per my project requirement if these apps are installed I need to take some action.

Answer (score 6):

Every app that can be opened via another app will have a registered URL scheme. You can find a directory of app URL schemes here: http://handleopenurl.com/

To see if an app is installed on the device, your device only needs to check if the URL scheme can be opened using UIApplication's canOpenUrl method.

So, to see if Facebook is installed, you could run the following

```
BOOL facebookInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://requests"]];
```

Unfortunately, it looks like there's no URL scheme registered for Gmail or LinkedIn.

Comment: hmm .. I should have rather asked if there is URL scheme available for linked in n gmail, right?

Comment: This is something you can verify yourself by examining the IPA file

Answer (score 0):

You can actually, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://"]]